# Can't edit or add widgets -- how can I restart widgets?

Tags: ventura, widgets

I am experiencing two issues with widgets on one of my Macs.
I have MacStudio and MacBook Pro(M1) running macOS Ventura. MacStudio has the issue.

Firstly, I can only access widget editing mode once after restarting the system. When I try to reaccess it after closing and reopening the widget panel, the edit button no longer works, and the widgets appear to freeze for edit.

Secondly, I cannot add new widgets or edit preexisting widgets when I am in editing mode. Clicking the green plus button or double-clicking on preexisting widgets does not work, nor does the "Edit Complete" button.

Is there a solution to this issue? Or is there a way to restart the widgets to resolve the problem?

Additional Note:
Mac Studio is connected to three displays. I suspected the (unusual) display configuration caused the symptom, so I unplugged two of them and kept only StudioDisplay, but it still had the same symptom.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open "Activity Monitor":

- use Launchpad -> Activiti Monitor *or*
- use Spotlight (`Cmd+Spacebar`) and type "Activity Monitor" followed by the return key

2. There is the search bar in the upper right corner Activity Monitor: type "Notif", then click on "Notification Center"
3. Kill "Notification Center": click on the `Stop` button in the top menu

Notification Center will be relaunched automatically after that